# Electron: how to serve files from appdata

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I feel like this is such a basic question but I have been at it for hours and seem to be spinning around the answer.  I have an electron app which I also used create-react-app on.  I have image files in the appData folder for the electron app and I want to be able to display them in the renderer  (using react) using an img tag.

I cannot seem to figure out how to do this.  Using an absolute path and file:// for the img src doesn't work.  I also tried to register a custom protocol but can't seem to get it to work, I just keep getting file not found (see below).  Any ideas or links would be appreciated.

```
  protocol.registerFileProtocol('poster', (request, callback) => {
    const url = request.url.substr(9)
    console.log(url);
    callback({path: app.getPath('appData')+'/posters/'+url})
  }, (error) => {
    if (error) console.error('Failed to register protocol')
  })
```

The image tag would look something like this:

```
<img src='poster://test.jpg'/>
```

Comment: I've got it sort of working now, I should have been using 'userData' instead of 'appData'.  The problem is that the protocol seems to convert the url I pass in as the src to lower case which then doesn't match with the file names.

Comment: Did you ever get this working correctly ?  I'm trying to do the same, I got a bunch of images that will be in the userdata folder and a react application that should load them.  I tried registering a protocol like you did, but I must be missing a lot of boilerplate cause I can't get it to work.  Do you have a full example of your attempt somewhere ?

Comment: I did get it working with lowercase filenames.  I put an answer below.  I don't have this project posted to github or anything but in terms of boilerplate, I believe I followed this (https://flaviocopes.com/react-electron/) tutorial.  The code below that I had in public/electron.js would go into src/start.js file of the tutorial, I must have reorganized the file structure in my code at some point.  Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a look when I get home.  I abandoned the boilerplate approach, and switched over to electron-forge https://electronforge.io/ This worked out of the box, it needed a little tweaking afterwards upgrading all the packages in the react-template.  But images showed instantly without a lot of fancy meddling.  A simple boilerplate start would be my preferred solution over a CLI tool though

Answer (score 2):

What I eventually ended up doing was correcting my original code to use userData instead of appData.  I didn't end up solving the part where it was converting to lower case so I just made all of my file names in lower case.

To find the path on your machine where you should put the files you can look at the result of a call to:

```
app.getPath('userData')
```

Here is the relevant code in my public/electron.js file:

```
  protocol.registerFileProtocol('poster', (request, callback) => {
          const url = request.url.substr(9,request.url.length -10)
          callback({path: app.getPath('userData')+'/posters/'+url})
        }, (error) => {
          if (error) console.error('Failed to register protocol')
        })

  }

  protocol.registerStandardSchemes(['poster'])
```

In my react code it is just a matter now of prefixing the filename in my image tag with 'poster://' so an image tag looks like:

```
<img src='poster://poster1.jpg/>
```